# Lenovo P51S - how can I turn off the touchpad

Tags: touchpad, lenovo, 17.10

The bios is current and although the touchpad is "off" in the bios Ubuntu still sees it. Guess that is a bios bug? In any case, how can i turn off the touchpad in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question I used this: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/131/touchpad-indicator/

please comment if a better approach. This works in 17.10 .

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.